# Pausing and resuming a Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#

```
    private bool isProcessing=false;
    public bool IsProcessing { get { return isProcessing; } }

    private bool IsTerminated=false;

    private bool isPaused=false;
    public bool IsPaused { get { return isPaused; } }
```

and this function which contains the `Parallel.ForEach`

```
private void StartProcess()
        {
            isPaused = IsTerminated = false;
            isProcessing = true;

            Parallel.ForEach(items, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (item, state) =>
                {
                    if (isPaused) state.Stop();
                    if (IsTerminated) state.Break();
                    item.Process();
                });

            isPaused = IsTerminated = false;
            isProcessing = false;
        }
```

consider the following, the StartProcess() got called, then  IsTerminated got set to true the loop breaks and same happens when isPaused set to true, i am not sure how i could resume the Parallel.ForEach after Stop() is called, how could i get the index of where each thread has started and stopped?

in the case of pause/resume i did it by adding a boolean value to the item object to indicate if it was processed,
and then on resume calling StartProcess() again and skipping the items that were processed, but i am sure there is a better way , a way in which i don't need to customize my object structure, another way is adding the processed items references to a list and skipping them on resume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the `ParallelLoopResult` back from the `Parallel.ForEach` call. It will tell you which was the last element processed.

Also you appear to have `Stop()` and `Break()` backwards. `Stop()` stops as soon as possible, some items below the last item you have processed may not have been processed yet. `Break()` stops as soon as possible, but it continues processing until all items that came before the current item has been processed, it then reports the index of the last processed item.

```
   private long? lowestBreakIndex = null;

    private void StartProcess()
    {
        isPaused = IsTerminated = false;
        isProcessing = true;

        ParallelLoopResult result = Parallel.ForEach(
            items.Skip(lowestBreakIndex ?? 0) //I am assuming that items is some form of ICollection. The Skip function will skip to the next item to process
            , new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (item, state) =>
            {
                //I swapped these two.
                if (isPaused) 
                    state.Break();
                else if (IsTerminated) 
                    state.Stop();
                else
                    item.Process();
            });

        lowestBreakIndex = result.LowestBreakIteration;

        isPaused = IsTerminated = false;
        isProcessing = false;
    }
```

Important note: You could potentially run the same item twice. Note the name of the propterty is **Lowest**BreakItteration, if two threads both report the break the lower of the two will be the one who reports it's result.

For more information about `Stop()` and `Break()` see [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461430/parallel-foreach-c-sharp-pause-and-stop-function/8461721#8461721) from another question about Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: so to resume the Parallel.ForEach i just call StartProcess() again? , shouldnt the lastProcessedIndex variable be outside the function?

Comment: but how do i know that it has completed, by comparing last processed index with what?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more explicit. I updated the answer, I also added a link to a old question of mine that goes in to more detail about the diffrences between Stop and Break. (I just happen to get a +1 on it earlier today so it was fresh in my mind)

Comment: i gave you that one and this one ;)

Comment: If you want to know if it was completed you will need to check `result.IsCompleted`, perhaps change your function to return `bool` instead of `void` and have it do `return result.IsCompleted;`

Comment: I made a few small changes to the code, also read the new "Important Note" at the bottom. If you can't have items being processed multiple times you will need to do the BlockingCollection solution with the `.GetConsumingPartitioner()` I mentioned in the other answer. (if you do go that route you can drop all the ParallelLoopResult stuff and just go back to your original code)

Comment: i already have a list of references to processed items so not problem with skipping them, i think its a better solution than the lowest break index, but still i have to lock that list

Comment: my items also has ids so a list of processed ids is a good option too and can be resumed even with a new instance of the app by serializing the list of ids, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

seems that u need

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx

create 4 threads if the computer has 4 cores.

Comment: i thought about the blocking collection, but i still prefer using the Parallel.ForEach which doesnt work well with a blocking collection

Comment: @user1492051 [it's not hard to fix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) so `BlockingCollection` will play nice with `Parallel.ForEach`, you just need a partitioner that takes one item at a time. The [Parallel Extensions Extras](http://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) library from Microsoft has that already built in, you just need to use the `.GetConsumingPartitioner()` extension method,